# How to extract the outputs of a network in keras?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network

Now, I follow a [project](https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet/blob/master/main.py), where the 18th line of code fit the model.

I want to extract the last output of this neural network. To be specific, I want to extract the "conv10" in the 53rd line of [code](https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet/blob/master/model.py).

I try type: model.outputs. But a don't know whether it is true and what it is.

Comment: Hi Tim. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include the relevant parts of the code as text inside the question. If this link goes dead in the future, your question will have no value to the community. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

In order to extract the output of a certain layer in your network you can do the following thing :

```
x = model.layers[N].output #will extract the N layer's output
```

so if you want the output of the last one :

```
x = model.layers[-1].output
```